# High CPU/MOBO temperature even after cleaning and reinstalling

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, battery, temperature

Even after dissembling my laptop and cleaning it, the temp of my CPU and Motherboard hangs around 41+ degrees Celsius while idle and no apps running. It used to be much lower and my laptop gets really hot. My battery life also deteriorated. Average battery life went from 8 hours to 5 hours.

What could be the problem? I'm not good with hardware

Comment: If battery live decreased since cleaning then it is likely using more power and thus getting hotter. That would make the problem be 'somehow it uses more power after maintenance'. I am not sure what would cause that though, assuming only hardware maintenance was done and nothing was changed in software.

Comment: I tried reinstalling Windows 8 after cleaning but that didn't help. I even tried Ubuntu but my temperature in while running Linux increased even more to 60 degrees Celsius. I'm guessing it's a BIOS error (I did reset all settings there) or it could be my charger. I am not sure

Comment: Is there a 'high performance' setting in the BIOS? Does the laptop have a discreet GPU and a GPU buildinto the APU/CPU? Is that set to 'aways use discrete graphics' ?  Etc etc.

Comment: I've tried forcing integrated graphics card but there is no difference, and no I couldn't find a high performance setting. Thanks for the help. I'm looking if I can update the BIOS.

Comment: There is a possibility for using more power on a laptop after cleaning, if the cpu did not throttle as much as it did before (just saying). A laptop doesnt get really hot until your doing something with it, you did not even indicate what your doing with it?  (or if something is using cpu behind the scenes) .  Did you refresh the thermal paste when you dissasembled cleaned it?  Moving heat sink stuff or even bumping it, when there is crusty old thermal goop under there , wouldnt improve it.

Comment: To comment on *"A laptop doesnt get really hot until your doing something with it, you did not even indicate what your doing with it?"* Full reinstall, only installed FireFox and RealTemp/CPU z and that's it. No applications were running in the background, I was purely monitoring my temperature.

Comment: Nothing wrong with even 50*C temps on a cpu when idling if there is a thermal responce from the fans (slower when not needed) as long as the cooling ramps up as needed.  One could only hope to stay at 50*C or even 60 always :-)  and the cooling system to agressivly respond as needed.  So your idle temps , which may seem high, are not an actual problem, what happens when it goes to work could be.  (when there is a thermal responce from the cooling).

Comment: Re-install of a windows system , the windows will be doing stuff , for a while that is supposed to improve the speed.  so there is a bit of background stuff going on for a few days after a full reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

While you were dissembling your laptop, Did you remove heat sinks then clean old one and put new Thermal Grease? If not!?, be sure you do it in right way! (Do not put too much of it! just check youtube videos)

Also be sure your cooler fans work properly. You can use any Free Hardware monitoring programs. (like: [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) or 'SpeedFan' or [Aida64](http://www.aida64.com/downloads) ...) Then make stress on your processor and watch fan speed reaction to processor heat!? (Aida64 have some stress functions to test hardware's)

**General Rule**: If you have your laptop for a long time or use it anywhere you go!? And If while you were cleaning it, you found out too many dust inside it, It will be a good idea to change all Thermal Grease under heat sinks. (This rule, even applies on Desktops too! Base on work area conditions, Cleaning Fans and Changing Thermal Grease after 6 months or 1 year.) Also sometimes we have to replace some fans too! Cleaning fans also have its own technique, The safest way to clean it is to use Blower on it. But if you gonna use brush on it make sure you know how to do it.